# Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value in Private network

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I created private network and mined some ether, when I was try to send some ether to another account in my private network I am getting "Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value - Private network" error.

Genesis.json

```
{
   "config": {
     "chainId": 4545,
     "homesteadBlock": 0,
     "eip155Block": 0,
     "eip158Block": 0
},
"alloc" : {},
"coinbase" : "0x75bcb134477f42f6fefbf177f9a610c0665e23a6",
"difficulty" : "0x20000",
"extraData" : "",
"gasLimit" : "0x2fefd8ffffffffff",
 "nonce" : "0x0000000000000042",
 "mixhash" : 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp" : "0x00"
}
```

Comment: most likely, the balance of the account sending transaction is 0 or very close to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the similar issue in my Dapp so i started sending gas amount in my transaction. I am new in this tech. but thought this information might help you.

ContractName.transaction(param1,param2, param3, {gas: '195253'});